# Ayuda creando una funcion en PostgreSQL que Inserte datps en las columnas con un caracter delimitador

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, codeigniter

Poseo una tabla con caracteres Nombre, Aepllido, Cedula y Fecha de Nacimiento, y recibo de mi programa una serie de sentencias similares a

```
Luis*Lopez*273982*24/12/1998|Juan*Gonzalez*232234*03/12/1987|Julio*Perez*274234*03/12/1995
```

Busco poder delimitar los insert usando dos caracteres especiales, donde el `|` sea el salto de linea y el `*` la inserción entre columnas

Logre solucionar el salto de linea entre tablas usando esta consulta

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table('Luis*Lopez*273982*24/12/1998|Juan*Gonzalez*232234*03/12/1987|Julio*Perez*274234*03/12/1995', '\|')
```

Pero aun no se me ocurre como crear la funcion que separe a través de * e inserte en las columnas, Gracias de antemano a los que puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table PERSONA(nombre varchar(50),apellido varchar(50),id varchar(50),fecha text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertar_comlumnas(entrada text) RETURNS int AS 
$$
    DECLARE
       fila RECORD;
       f_persona PERSONA%ROWTYPE;
       columnas text[];
       i_sql text;
    BEGIN
       FOR fila IN  SELECT regexp_split_to_table(entrada, '\|') LOOP
              select regexp_split_to_array(fila::text, E'\\*') into columnas;
              f_persona.nombre:=columnas[1];
              f_persona.apellido:=columnas[2];
              f_persona.id:=columnas[3];
              f_persona.fecha:=columnas[4];
              select 'INSERT INTO PERSONA VALUES($1.*) ' into i_sql;
              EXECUTE format(i_sql) USING f_persona;
       END LOOP;

        RETURN 1;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que buscaba, me ayudo bastante, solo le hice unas pequeñas adaptaciones segun mi codigo, pero me funciono bastante bien, aunque me surgio una duda con el codigo, los registros los inserta el primero y el ultimo de cada fila con paréntesis, se lo he intentado quitar aunque no he podido y desconozco la razón del porque ocurre eso

Comment: Ya solucione amigo, lo termine adaptando asi
    BEGIN
 fila := regexp_split_to_array(entrada, E'\\|');
 FOREACH row IN ARRAY fila
 LOOP 
  RAISE NOTICE '%', row;
  columna := regexp_split_to_array(row, E'\\*');
  insert into test.persona values(columna[1],columna[2],columna[3],columna[4]);    
 END LOOP;

Answer (score 0):

Si es desde PHP puedes hacer una combinación de `explode` -  `explode` - `implode`.

Necesariamente tendrás que hacer un primer `explode`  usando `|` para cada fila y luego un `explode` usando `*`  para cada columna.

Luego, con el array de columnas puedes hacer `implode` para representarlas separadas por `,` por ejemplo, un formato óptimo para inserción en base de datos por ejemplo.

He aquí cómo sería la obtención:

```
$str="Luis*Lopez*273982*24/12/1998|Juan*Gonzalez*232234*03/12/1987|Julio*Perez*274234*03/12/1995";
$arrFilas=explode("|",$str);
foreach ($arrFilas as $row){
    $arrColumns=explode("*",$row);
    echo implode(',',$arrColumns).PHP_EOL;
}
```

El resultado sería:

```
Luis,Lopez,273982,24/12/1998
Juan,Gonzalez,232234,03/12/1987
Julio,Perez,274234,03/12/1995
```

Como ves, te muestra cada fila y luego cada columna separada por comas.